# php scandir, readdir, etc not showing file list and return false even has been using chmod -R 0777

Tags: php

first sorry if this question had already answered or another stupid question, just let me know where i can find the answer if already answer.

today, i'm using scandir for get list dir from another site that locate same machine but i failed to get list even i had run chmod -R 0777 fot it dir.

```
# all bellow code run from site2.com
$location = "/var/www/vhosts/site1.com/site1.com/httpdocs/webdata/";

# this return FALSE
$files = scandir($location);  # return FALSE
$res = opendir($location);
$files = readdir($res);  # return FALSE
closedir($res);

# i try this after chmod -R 0777 /var/www/vhosts/site1.com/site1.com/httpdocs/webdata/
# from terminal with admin account, but still ... FALSE :-(
print(is_readable($location) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');  # print FALSE
```

i solved this problem by using exec function, but it seem not recommended (especially on cpanel). And the question is why i still can not get is_readable function return true after chmod ? from search google and php it self do not explain why this can happen, i had already find the way to get file list but still i want to know why it can be happen (after run chmod -R 0777).

note: i'm the administrator for that machine, all website on that machine belong to me so i'm not try to hack any client website and using ehcp for hosting control panel.

Thank You.

i fond it, that cause restrict by 'open_basedir' on php setting or on apache setting.

vey sorry.

Comment: what is your document root ?

Comment: thank you, for your clue. i had found the problem, it's cause open_basedir on php setting or apache setting.